# What's the length limit for submitting form data via jquery ajax using serialize and post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

I want to use jquery ajax to submit a form and update it.  It works fine with a small amount of data but chokes when I have more data.  Is there an inherent limit to this method, or am I on a wild goose chase here?

Here is my save function

```
function customSave(){
  var page = document.getElementById("page").value;
  var companyid = document.getElementById("companyid").value;
  var formdata = $('#mainform').serialize();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'transactionsbin-update.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: formdata,
    success: function() {
      reloadList(companyid,page);
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Save failed");
    }
  });
}
```

The page I'm updating is a list of financial transactions that are selected out of the database based on user specified criteria.  So depending on the search criteria the user enters, the list of transactions could be long or short.  Each transaction has between 7 and 10 inputs, depending on the transaction type, plus there are a number of other inputs in the form that I'm submitting.

Basically what I've noticed is that if I have a few transactions (3 for example) there doesn't seem to be any problem, but if I have a page full of transactions (26 for example) it falls over.

I know this because I'm looking in Chrome's developer tools, network tab and if I click on the update page url it displays a 404 error.  It also, by the way, displays a method of GET, even though I clearly specified POST in my ajax call.

The following url fails.  It is 11,234 characters long.

```
https://timesavr.net/dev/transactionsbin-update.php?searchinput=&fromdate=2014-03-01&todate=2014-03-11&activefamiliescbx=on&inactivefamiliescbx=on&chargescbx=on&paymentscbx=on&debitcbx=on&creditcbx=on&chequecbx=on&cashcbx=on&moneyordercbx=on&bankdraftcbx=on&eftcbx=on&paypalcbx=on&emailcbx=on&tdcbx=on&nontdcbx=on&familyid%5B%5D=265&transactiontype%5B%5D=C&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=10&transactionid%5B%5D=133033&transactionreference%5B%5D=0527&listchargeitems%5B%5D=34&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=25&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9740731&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=08&transactionid%5B%5D=133031&transactionreference%5B%5D=106&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=-2.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=MNY&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=N&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=Reimbursement+stuff&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=55&transactiontype%5B%5D=C&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=07&transactionid%5B%5D=133032&transactionreference%5B%5D=0526&listchargeitems%5B%5D=34&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=25.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=265&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=133016&transactionreference%5B%5D=21&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=545.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=BNK&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=Stuff+in+IE&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=265&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=133001&transactionreference%5B%5D=125&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=777.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=CHQ&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9732415&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=133002&transactionreference%5B%5D=102&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=888.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=CHQ&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=265&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=133003&transactionreference%5B%5D=444&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=444.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=CHQ&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9732415&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=133004&transactionreference%5B%5D=555&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=555.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=CHQ&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Father&transactionpayer%5B%5D=F&familyid%5B%5D=265&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=133007&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=345.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=BNK&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9730051&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=133000&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=650.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=CHQ&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=Testing&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=265&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=133006&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=345.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=CSH&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=N&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=265&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=133005&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=654.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=DBT&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9732415&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=132999&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=550.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=CHQ&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=Testing&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9730051&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=133009&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=345.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=BNK&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=265&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=132998&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=450.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=CHQ&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=Testing&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9730051&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=132994&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=88.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=MNY&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=asdfdddd&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9732415&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=132996&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=55.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=CHQ&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=ddreee&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9732415&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=132993&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=855.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=MNY&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=asdfdddd&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=265&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=132992&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=350.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=MNY&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=asdfdddd&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9732415&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=133008&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=345.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=BNK&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Father&transactionpayer%5B%5D=F&familyid%5B%5D=9730051&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=132997&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=66.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=CHQ&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=ddreee&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=265&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=132995&transactionreference%5B%5D=&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=22.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=CHQ&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=ddreee&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9730051&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=133018&transactionreference%5B%5D=15&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=887.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=BNK&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=Stuff+in+IE&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9732415&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=06&transactionid%5B%5D=133017&transactionreference%5B%5D=2&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=877.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=BNK&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=Stuff+in+IE&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Father&transactionpayer%5B%5D=F&familyid%5B%5D=265&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=04&transactionid%5B%5D=133019&transactionreference%5B%5D=654425&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=12.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=EFT&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=Testing+FireFox+Now&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9732415&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=04&transactionid%5B%5D=133020&transactionreference%5B%5D=54&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=45.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=EFT&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=Testing+FireFox+Now&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Father&transactionpayer%5B%5D=F&familyid%5B%5D=9730051&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=04&transactionid%5B%5D=133021&transactionreference%5B%5D=556&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=12%2C211.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=EFT&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=Testing+FireFox+Now&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&submittoken=&submitaction=&currenttime24=10%3A46&mm_noteentitytype=&mm_noteentityid=&mm_noteidtodelete=&_=1394556415701
```

Where as this one submits without a problem.  It is 1,566 characters long.

```
https://timesavr.net/dev/transactionsbin-update.php?searchinput=&fromdate=2014-03-07&todate=2014-03-11&activefamiliescbx=on&inactivefamiliescbx=on&chargescbx=on&paymentscbx=on&debitcbx=on&creditcbx=on&chequecbx=on&cashcbx=on&moneyordercbx=on&bankdraftcbx=on&eftcbx=on&paypalcbx=on&emailcbx=on&tdcbx=on&nontdcbx=on&familyid%5B%5D=265&transactiontype%5B%5D=C&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=10&transactionid%5B%5D=133033&transactionreference%5B%5D=0527&listchargeitems%5B%5D=34&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=25&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=9740731&transactiontype%5B%5D=P&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=08&transactionid%5B%5D=133031&transactionreference%5B%5D=106&listchargeitems%5B%5D=0&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=-2.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=MNY&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=N&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=Reimbursement+stuff&transactionpayerlabel%5B%5D=Mother&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&familyid%5B%5D=55&transactiontype%5B%5D=C&transactionyear%5B%5D=2014&transactionmonth%5B%5D=03&transactionday%5B%5D=07&transactionid%5B%5D=133032&transactionreference%5B%5D=0526&listchargeitems%5B%5D=34&listtransactionamount%5B%5D=25.00&transactionpaymenttype%5B%5D=&transactiontaxdeductible%5B%5D=Y&transactionhistorycomment%5B%5D=&transactionpayer%5B%5D=M&submittoken=&submitaction=&currenttime24=10%3A54&mm_noteentitytype=&mm_noteentityid=&mm_noteidtodelete=&_=1394556855187
```

I know that most browsers have limits on querystring lengths (I'm using Chrome for my testing) but I also read that using method: POST in jquery ajax should behave like a POST not a GET and a real POST does not submit anything on the querystring, although jquery appears to.  So I guess the second part of my question is, what is the difference really between using POST and GET in a jquery ajax call?

Comment: `method: 'POST',` should be `type: 'POST',`

Comment: Wow.  That's exactly what the problem was.  Thanks a lot!  I spent four hours coding alternate methods for updating including looping and instant updating all for naught.  It never ceases to amaze me how often seemingly complex problems are the result of simple typos.  sigh.  If you submit it as an answer I will credit you for it.